# User Tokens in menu are visible only when cache is cleared.

Tags: drupal-7

I am using **Menu Token** (menu_token) module to use "users token" in menu in order to display current users name in menu like this :

**Welcome [current-user:name]**

Whenever I login to site, it shows just Welcome , but when I clear cache it displays username. I also tried to clear cache on login using drupal_flush_all_caches() function but it was helpless. What should I do to resolve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Drupal Token is creating issue. Whenever we are using lots of caching module like memcache, APC or aggregate JS/CSS modules then this type of issue is arise. One possible solution for this is instead of using token menu module use custom drupal code or [Welcome User](https://www.drupal.org/project/welcome_username) Drupal module

After installing this module you have to select region to display "welcome user" block.

Comment: That worked like a charm for me. I have installed "Welcome User" module and it worked. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with token except in webforms.